# Super() the first thing to do

Tags: java, super

So I have this code.

```
public class HourlyWorker extends Worker {

private int hours;
public HourlyWorker(String name, int salRate,int hours) {
    super(name, salRate);
    this.hours=hours;
}

@Override
void computePay() {
    int pay;
    if(hours<60)
    {
        System.out.println("haha");
        pay=super.getSalRate()*hours;   //CALLING SUPER HERE.
        System.out.println("pay of"+super.getName()+"="+pay);
    }

}

}
```

Now in the `Worker` class, I have this method getSalRate.
I was told that `super` shall be the first line of code in a method. But if I am here calling it in the middle(the expression given); It works just fine.

Can someone tell me, what really do you mean, when someone says that `"Make Sure That Super Is The First Line Of Code`

Is It just for the constructors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The enforcement of first calling `super()` only applies in constructors. Even if it's left out, a call to the default `super()` constructor is inserted during compilation.

Answer (score 1):

In a constructor, you can optionally call the superclass constructor with `super`, on the first line of the constructor only. If you don't, the default superclass constructor is called implicitly.

Elsewhere, you can use `super` anywhere within a method, initializer or constructor to access a superclass member.

Answer (score 0):

It will just initialise the super class (Worker class) with the parameters passed to the HourlyWorker constructor.

It needs to be called at the start of the constructor. Super can be used on any line elsewhere.